# Converting XML security config to Java config

Tags: spring-security

I am at my wits end trying to convert the below XML based config to a POJO based config:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

<bean id="auth0EntryPoint" class="com.auth0.spring.security.auth0.Auth0AuthenticationEntryPoint" />

<!-- all urls starting with unsecured are -->
<security:http pattern="${auth0.securedRoute}" create-session="stateless"  entry-point-ref="auth0EntryPoint" use-expressions="false">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="${auth0.securedRoute}" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <security:custom-filter ref="auth0Filter" after="SECURITY_CONTEXT_FILTER" ></security:custom-filter>
    <security:csrf disabled="true"></security:csrf> 
</security:http>

<!-- Otherwise by default everything is secured -->
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"  pattern="/**" create-session="stateless"  entry-point-ref="auth0EntryPoint">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access='permitAll' />
    <security:csrf disabled="true"></security:csrf>
</security:http>

<bean id="auth0Filter" class="com.auth0.spring.security.auth0.Auth0AuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="entryPoint" ref="auth0EntryPoint"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="auth0AuthenticationProvider" class="com.auth0.spring.security.auth0.Auth0AuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="clientSecret" value="${auth0.clientSecret}" ></property>
    <property name="clientId" value="${auth0.clientId}" ></property>
    <property name="securedRoute" value="${auth0.securedRoute}" ></property>
</bean>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="auth0AuthenticationProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>
```

At the moment, I have something like this:

```
package com.simplymeasured.uam;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;

import com.auth0.spring.security.auth0.Auth0AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import com.auth0.spring.security.auth0.Auth0AuthenticationFilter;
import com.auth0.spring.security.auth0.Auth0AuthenticationProvider;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(auth0EntryPoint());
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http
            .addFilter(auth0Filter());
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated();
        System.out.println("CONFIGURE GETTING CALLED");
        super.configure(http);
    }


    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        Auth0AuthenticationProvider  provider = new Auth0AuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setClientId("<auth0client>");
        provider.setClientSecret("<auth0secret>");
        provider.setSecuredRoute("/v2/**");
        return provider;
    }

    public Auth0AuthenticationFilter auth0Filter() {
        Auth0AuthenticationFilter auth0Filter = new Auth0AuthenticationFilter();
        auth0Filter.setEntryPoint(auth0EntryPoint());
        return auth0Filter;
    }

    public Auth0AuthenticationEntryPoint auth0EntryPoint() {
        Auth0AuthenticationEntryPoint auth0EntryPoint = new Auth0AuthenticationEntryPoint();
        return auth0EntryPoint;
    }


}
```

but it has been through dozens of iterations and I am just not getting anything lined up where it needs to be. At the moment I am dealing with an issue where it is claiming that the filter chain is already a defined bean, so no requests are going through. Any help or hints would be immense, I haven't found a reference book for spring-security-4, so I am just trying to cobble together code samples.

Answer (score 0):

I am convinced that I am fated to only get relevant search results once I post my question: [Why isn’t this Spring Security AuthenticationProvider found after being Java configured?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304856)