# Spring security csrf disabled, still get an Invalid CSRF token found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, csrf

I'm having issues with csrf, even though its disabled in the spring configuration.
My log outputs this:

```
Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8080/exercise/
```

I have this spring configuration

```
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user/add").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST).hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "TRAINER")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE).hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "TRAINER")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.HEAD).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/register/").authenticated()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();
   }
```

Seems like i get authenticated and authorized, since the log outputs:

```
Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@1ddb0b4b: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@1ddb0b4b: Principal: com.brevisfit.api.model.user.User[ iduser=1 ]; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_TRAINER'
```

I have issues with POST\DELETE\PUT request since they throw a 403 response, which I understand comes from the CsrfFilter.class

```
if (!csrfToken.getToken().equals(actualToken)) {
            if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                this.logger.debug("Invalid CSRF token found for "
                        + UrlUtils.buildFullRequestUrl(request));
            }
```

For the requests, I'm using postman.

Comment: Where did you put this `configure` method? Is it in a configuration class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`?

Comment: did you manage to find, what was wrong? Or how did you fix it?

Comment: Anyone managed to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your AuthenticationBuilder should be @Autowired.

```
@Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());

    }
```

[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304856/why-isn-t-this-spring-security-authenticationprovider-found-after-being-java-con)

Comment: added `@autowired` to my configure method for AuthenticationManagerBuilder but no success. Also, my issue is different than the one you referenced. As for me, I get all the right authorisations. Its the csrf filter that throws and exception

Answer (score 0):

If CSRF is set to disabled and yet the error is still appearing, it likely means the code isn't being executed. Take a step back to check basic assumptions e.g. Was the code built before running? Is the test running the correct version of the code?

For me, the class containing the SecurityFilterChain disabling the CSRF was moved to a library and I hadn't noticed. Hence, my IDE was only recompiling the application code...